# First things first with Ajax

Tags: 7, ajax

Somehow I can't get through the first Ajax lesson.

This is the code of a simple module that I put together:

```
function myajax_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['myajax/param/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'dynamic_products_ajax_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => TRUE, // array('access dynamic_products content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}

function myajax_ajax_callback($type = 'ajax', $param){
   if ($type == 'ajax') {
    $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#myajax_wrapper', '[Content returned for argument ' . $param . ' will be here]');
    $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
    ajax_deliver($page);
  }  else {
    $output = t("This is some content delivered via a page load.");
    return $output;
  }
}
```

This is my markup.

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');

// Output a link
print l(t('AJAX 12'), 'myajax/param/12', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('use-ajax'))));
print l(t('AJAX 20'), 'myajax/param/20', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('use-ajax'))));
// Output a wrapper
print '<div id="myajax_wrapper"></div>';
?>
```

All I'm getting is a JavaScript alert that informs me about AJAX error that occurred, and the result code is 200.

Is the example module missing anything?

**Question revision:**

After much googling I've come up with a very rudimentary working Ajax example that does what I want - it replaces HTML of a wrapper with a response obtained from a dynamic link. Hope it'll be of some help for newbies.

Module:

```
<?php
function myajax_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['myajax/param/nojs/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'myajax_ajax_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(2,3),
    'access arguments' => TRUE,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  $items['myajax/param/ajax/%'] = array(
    'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
  ) + $items['myajax/param/nojs/%'];

  return $items;
}

function myajax_ajax_callback($ajax, $param){
    $is_ajax = $ajax === 'ajax';

    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');

    if ($is_ajax) {
      $commands = array();
      $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#myajax_wrapper', "This is some content delivered via a page load with param <b>" . $param . "</b>.");

      return array(
        '#type' => 'ajax',
        '#commands' => $commands,
      );
    } else {
      drupal_set_message(t('JavaScript should be enabled to avoid page reloads.'));
      drupal_goto();
    }
}
```

The markup:

```
<?php
print l(t('AJAX 12 '), 'myajax/param/nojs/12', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('use-ajax'))));
print l(t('AJAX 20 '), 'myajax/param/nojs/20', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('use-ajax'))));
?>

<div id="myajax_wrapper"></div>
```

The problem with disappearing admin_menu persists. If anyone could tell me why...

Comment: Your page callback is defined as `dynamic_products_ajax_callback` but your function name is `myajax_ajax_callback`...my money's on that :)

Comment: Unfortunately you lost your dimes :( That naming discrepancy was only the reason for my admin_menu disappearing, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Use Firefox with Firebug and check the ajax request. What parameters are sent and what is the raw answer?

Comment: Request is OK, the response is complete HTML displayed as alert box. Since the box is taller than my screen I don't really know what it wants to tell me. Should ajax_deliver($page) be used for returning just a tiny json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems with your original (first) question are as follows:

- Your callback function expects 2 parameters, but you are providing just one.
- You are missing `nojs` in your url.
- You are giving `param` as a parameter to your callback function, but you wanna `%` instead/

So it should look like something like this:

```
  $items['myajax/param/nojs/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'myajax_ajax_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(2,3), // drupal starts counting from 0 so nojs is 2nd and % is 3th arg
    'access arguments' => TRUE,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
```

I hope this will help someone.

P.S.
sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the examples seem to be all concerned with forms. It does seem difficult to find a place where you can find a solution that is just click a link and get a html response.

This is my version

## Menu

```
function hottopicsnotify_menu() {
 $items = array();
 $items[HOTTOPICSNOTIFY_MODULE_NAME . '/pause'] = array(
  'title' => 'Share Hot Topic with Public',
  'access callback' => 'hottopicsnotify_access_callback',
  'page callback' => 'hottopicsnotify_pause',
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'file' => 'includes/HotTopicsAcceptanceVote.php',
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

## Template

Complicated, call block from template file to get this result in the source code. Render block to get 'id' set.

```
<section class="hottopics-paused">
    <div id="paused-ajax-container">
  Hot topics Voting <span style="color:red">Paused</span>.   <a href="/hottopicsnotify/pause" id="ajax-link">Start</a>
</div>
```

Without digressing into how to render a block, the shortcut way is calling render on a block content array.

```
<?php 
 $block['content'] = array(
 '#type' => 'link',
 '#title' => 'Pause',
 '#href' => '/hottopicsnotify/pause',
 '#ajax' => array(
   'effect' => 'fade',
 ),
);

print render($block['content']); ?>
```

## Call back function

```
/**
 * Toggle the pause variable.
 */
function hottopicsnotify_pause() {
 $paused = variable_get(HOTTOPICSNOTIFY_EDITORIAL_BOARD_PAUSED, FALSE);
 drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');

 $block['content'] = array(
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => 'Pause',
  '#href' => '/hottopicsnotify/pause',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'effect' => 'fade',
  ),
 );

 $response_text =  "Hot topics report running. " . render($block['content']);
...

 $commands = array();
 $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#paused-ajax-container', 
 $response_text);
 ajax_deliver(array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands));
 drupal_exit();
}
```